# Calender and to do task list using data structures

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am looking to make a calendar and task list for any corresponding day - just like most of the calendar apps. Main purpose of this practice is to use data structures effectively. 
I have thought of two approaches:

1. Use array for calender days and then make a linked list of tasks for corresponding days.
2. Use linked lists for both.

Another question is: Can i use trees in the above scenario?
Maybe i am totally wrong. Kindly guide me through, i am keen to learn.

Note: i will be using c++ as my tool but not STL.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach is more efficient in terms of time complexity as the tasks associated with any day can be accessed in constant time in an array. But the downside is that it will use much more space than a linked list.
If you use a linked list for the calendar days, you can add a new node for each day one at a time, rather than all at once (like in arrays). So the final space usage will be the same in both cases .

As far as trees are concerned, you can use [Map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) - like [Associative containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers), which are usually implemented as [Self-balancing BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), thus giving you decent efficiency, in terms of both, time (logarithmic) and space/memory (Proportional to the number of days stored in the calendar, but no space wastage, unlike arrays). You can associate a date to a linked list of strings in this case.

If I were you, I'd be using `map<date,vector<string> >` though.

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned. I have to use basic structures so i am not going to use STL. Considering your answer i guess i can use second approach in a way that user can make a new day entry and task list when required. Can i use binary trees? Kindly, put some more light on it!

Comment: umm, yes you can use [Binary Search Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with nodes sorted with respect to dates, with each node having a linked list of strings representing tasks. That is the "key" of a node will be the date and the "data" stored within a node will be the linked list of strings.

Comment: A plain Binary tree won't be of much use though, as it would not be much different from the linked list implementation (option 2), and will be pretty inefficient.

Comment: I was also thinking about that. I guess, i will be using 2nd option since main purpose was to use data structures. anyways, thanks for your prompt help

Comment: I believe you can implement map using hashing (need not use STL). That way, you would be able to access the task lists of a specific in day in O(1) as opposed to O(logN) when using BST